# Missing matplotlib api docs

Tags: matplotlib, document

Some of the matplotlib api docs seem to have no api documentation. See [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/backend_qt5agg_api.html). There are just the following words:

> NOTE Not included, to avoid adding a dependency to building the docs.

What does this mean to a person seeking documentation?

Does this mean there are not and will never be documentation for that portion of the api?

Comment: My guess is that this would require an actual dependency on Qt5, and since it's an "internal" or rarely-used part of the package, it was deemed "worth it" to avoid that dependency.

Comment: @bnaecker Well, earlier versions have the documentation. See [this](https://matplotlib.org/2.1.2/api/backend_qt5agg_api.html). How can it ever be "worth it" to omit api description? How can anyone know how to use the api without documentation? Do we have to decipher the source code?

Comment: It's definitely odd that documentation was *removed*. I've no idea why that might be done. But documentation, like any other part of the code, requires resources to write and maintain. If the part of the project in question is something like this, a specific GUI backend, the project maintainers may decide that those resources are better spent elsewhere.